# Как загрузить содержимое страницы по протоколу tls в renpy?

Tags: python, https, ssl, tls

Как получить содержимое https страницы, при условии что нельзя использовать `urllib.urlopen()`? Сама страница выдает информацию в виде json, протокол шифрования — TLS 1.2. Нужен обходной путь, что-то отличимое от urlopen.

**Обновление**

Есть движок для игр, `renpy`, Я хочу сделать крутые фишки. Сделал на питоне, все работает. Перенес код в `renpy`, возвращает ошибку

> unknown url type; "https"

Скорее всего это из-за того, что не установлена по стандарту бибилиотека ssl (в этом движке можно импортировать библиотеки питона, которые собраны там почти все (стандартные)). А поскольку `urlib,urlopen()` использует ssl если тип = "https", оно и не находит ничего (я смотрел исходники бибилиотеки). Вот и спрашиваю решение. Request не подходит по двум параметрам:

1. Она не установлена сначала.
2. Тоже использует ssl (скорее всего).

Comment: A `requests.get` подайдёт? Откуда такое ограничение?

Comment: Не помещайте информацию необходимую, чтобы ответить на вопрос в комментарии, отредактируйте ваш вопрос вместо этого. `ssl` присутствует в стандартной библиотеке как минимум с Python 2.6. `from pip._vendor import requests` должно работать на текущем Python 2.7 и выше. Существуют библиотеки, которые реализуют TLS на чистом Питоне, но это на любителя. Если у вас нестандартное окружение, то опишите его подробно: какая версия Питона, какие основные отличия (например, есть ли ctypes), можете ли свои файлы добавлять итд.

Comment: Первая ссылка в гугле предлагает скомпилировать renpy самостоятельно. (Вторая ссылка ведёт на этот вопрос :) Если это не мод к игре, то может оказаться вариантом

Comment: Мод к игре. Видимо решения для загрузки страниц https нет.